# Draggable row in Gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, draggable, rows

Hey guys,
i have a gridview, now i want to make the rows draggable, so that user can change the sort order of the gridview, and also the datasource should get affect, so that i can save the latest order in the database.

Please give some suggestion or samples, how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you find a different control. Dragging rows is not a feature that most major ASP.NET control makers have implemented for grids, besides do your really think your users will want to sort in this way?  Clicking on the column header is the preferred method for a very good reason.

Comment: Yes sorting using column header is the preferred method, but what if user wants to sort in specific order, say clicking on column will sort in ASC or DESC order, now within this record, if user just want to move record up or down, then ColumnHeader Sorting wont do that, right? what could be done in this case.

Comment: ASC or DESC are the default sorts, but you can always provide a custom sort. Using events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at jqGrid - here is their [example](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx) specific to ASP.NET webforms

Comment: I don't see row dragging as part of the jqGrid.

Comment: Look at http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. Choose on the left tree "New in Version 3.6" and then "Drag and Drop Rows - it shows between two grids, but could be done with 1